# Analytic function in extended plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Which of the following statements are true?
1.Every function analytic in the extended plane is constant.
2.If f(z) is entire function such that f(z)=u+iv and $u^2\le v^2+2012$,
      then f(z)is constant.

I guess first option is wrong because if I take f(z)=sinz then f is not constant but second option is correct using Picard's Theorem.Is it correct?

Comment: $\sin z$ is not analytic at $z=\infty$.  I assume "extended plane" means $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: Is that means both statements are true?

Answer (score 2):

1. If $f$ is analytic in $ \infty$ then $ L:=\lim_{z \to \infty}f(z)$ exists.

Its your turn to show that then $f$ is bounded on $ \mathbb C$.

2. If $u^2\le v^2+2012$ then $u^2-v^2 \le 2012$, hence $Re(f^2) \le 2012$.

Can you now argue with Picard's Theorem ?

Comment: That means real part of f is bounded and f is entire and hence f is constant.

Comment: Yes. That is a right argument.

Comment: You don't need Picard's theorem. $f^2$ maps the plane to a half plane, which is conformally equivalent to the unit disc. Compose with this conformal map and apply Liouville.

Comment: I have a doubt,can we say that every analytic function in extended plane is bounded?

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE No, it means $\text {Re }f^2$ is bounded above.

Comment: @Fred Attempt for showing that $f$ must be bdd:   Consider the chain (w.r.t set inclusion) of compact disks $D(0,n)$ of radius $n$ centered at $0$. Take $M_n=\sup_{z \in D(0,n)} |f(z)|$. Now, $M_n≥M_{n-1}≥...$. If $L$ is an upper bound, we're done. If not then $\exists$ $f(z_k)=M_k>L$. [Using compactness of disk, the supremum is attained]. Now, if such $z_k$'s are finite, then take $\max_k f(z_k)$ as the bound. If not, we get a a seq ${f(z_k)} \to \infty$, contradicting the very existence of limit. Is this okay???